# Not sure why I am getting a null pointer exception when converting 2D array to 1D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file-handling

I am creating a class that reads in some data from Google Finance. This is handled through my getStockInfo method. I am now trying to create two methods that extract certain elements of the 2D array that is created by the getStockInfo method, and initialise a 1D array.

More specifically, the file that is called from Google Finance is a CSV and I only want to access the 1st and 5th column (0 and 4). These two classes are called dataExtract and priceExtract. My IDE shows no errors when I am writing the code however when I run the class, I am getting a nullPointerException and I am not really sure why. I am guessing it's something to do with how I am converting the 2D array into a 1D array, but lost as to why.

Also, am I doing the best procedure of converting 2D arrays to 1D arrays? Essentially I need to create an array that can be accessed by another class to perform some statistical equations on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am getting the null pointer exceptions with the from the dateExtract and priceExtract methods. The getStockInfo method works perfectly.

EDIT 2: The statements "date = dataArray[0]" and "String [] priceString = dataArray[4]" are referenced when the error occurs.

```
public synchronized String[][] getStockInfo(final String symbol, final String stockExhange) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = " ";
    String splitBy = ",";
    ArrayList<String[]> googleData = new ArrayList<String[]>( );
    try {
        URL googleFin = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk/finance/historical?q=" 
                                    + stockExhange + "%3A" 
                                    + symbol + "&ei=l-d4UvCSM7SAwAOsxwE&output=csv");
        URLConnection gf = googleFin.openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gf.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            googleData.add(line.split(splitBy));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    int size = googleData.size(); //The number of elements in the data ArrayList
    String[][] dataArray = new String[5][size]; //The 6 elements are for each column of the CSV Google Finance produces
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            dataArray[i][j]=googleData.get(j)[i];//Turn into 2D Array rather than ArrayList and transpose
            System.out.println(dataArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return dataArray; 
}    

public String[] dateExtract(String[][] dataArray) {
    String[] date;
    date = dataArray[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(date[i]);
    }
    return date;
}

public double[] priceExtract(String[][] dataArray) {
    String[] priceString = dataArray[4];
    double[] priceDouble = new double[priceString.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        priceDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(priceString[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(priceDouble[i]);
    }
    return priceDouble;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get your NullPointerException?

Comment: And why are you "handling" all those exceptions just by printing a stack trace and then continuing as if nothing was wrong?

Comment: In `dateExtract` use `date.length`. Similar in priceExtract `priceString.length` and not `dateArray.length` which will do only the first five.

Comment: Would you like to give more details, probably the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you for you comments. I have updated my original post accordingly. I am handling the exceptions when downloading the file from Google Finance to demonstrate to my teacher that I understand error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. I created two file reader methods, each handling the 2d conversion.

Thanks for your comments.